# Does STDERR go to syslog in an LSB init script?

Tags: syslog, daemon, init.d, stderr

I am running a Debian system and have an init script in `/etc/init.d/` that starts a daemon using `start-stop-daemon`:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/myproject.pid --exec /usr/bin/somebin || return 2
```

If `/usr/bin/somebin` writes to STDERR, does that output automatically get written to the syslog? Or do I have to do something explicit to get output to STDERR into the syslog?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got a Debian based handy to test, but I remember it doesn't automatically redirect to the syslog. You must manually handle with something like this:

```
>> /var/log/myproject.log 2>&1
```